# typescript tuple, server-side angular6

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm updating my app from angular4 to angular6 and building as server-side render, however, the build brakes on this part of the code, I think is related to typescript upgrade from version 2.3 to 2.7 and upgrading to the lastest typescript version 2.8.3 bring more errors. And it's running fine as typescript 2.3 angular4

The app works fine as aot or jit, but breaks when I try to build as server-side render

This is the error:

```
        ERROR in ./src/app/components/core/global.config.ts
        Module parse failed: Unexpected token (345:26)
        You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
        |     };
        |     Connection.ConnectionsDev = (_a = {},
        |         _a[0 /* testOne */..valueOf()] = 'http://localhost:59384/api/testOne',
        |         _a[1 /* testTwo */..valueOf()] = 'http://localhost:59384/api/testTwo',
        |         _a[2 /* testThree */..valueOf()] = 'http://localhost:59384/api/testThree',
```

this is the code as typescript 2.3.2

```
        import { Injectable, EventEmitter, Output, isDevMode } from '@angular/core';
        import { Http, Headers } from '@angular/http';
        import { Subject } from 'rxjs';

        export const enum ConnectionServiceEnum {
            testOne,
            testTwo,
            testThree
        }

        @Injectable()
        export class GlobalConfig {
            ...
        }

        export class Connection {
            private static readonly ConnectionsDev: { [serviceName: number]: string } = {
                [ConnectionServiceEnum.testOne.valueOf()]: 'http://localhost:59384/api/testOne',
                [ConnectionServiceEnum.testTwo.valueOf()]: 'http://localhost:59384/api/testTwo',
                [ConnectionServiceEnum.testThree.valueOf()]: 'http://localhost:59384/api/testThree'
            };
        }
```

Any ideas?

tsconfig.json

```
        {
          "compileOnSave": false,
          "compilerOptions": { 
            "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
            "target": "es5",
            "module": "commonjs",
            "moduleResolution": "node",
            "sourceMap": true,
            "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
            "experimentalDecorators": true,
            "lib": [ "es2015", "dom" ],
            "noImplicitAny": false,
            "suppressImplicitAnyIndexErrors": false,
            "types": [ "node", "lodash" ],
            "typeRoots": [
              "node_modules/@types",
            ],   
          },
          "angularCompilerOptions": {
            "fullTemplateTypeCheck": true,
            "preserveWhitespaces": true,
          },
        }
```

tsconfig.server.json

```
        {
          "extends": "../tsconfig.json",
          "compilerOptions": {
            "outDir": "../out-tsc/app",
            "baseUrl": "./",
            "module": "commonjs",
            "types": []
          },
          "exclude": [
            "test.ts",
            "**/*.spec.ts",
            "server.ts"
          ],
          "angularCompilerOptions": {
            "entryModule": "app/app.server.module#AppServerModule"
          }
        }
```

package.json

```
        {
          "name": "angular",
          "version": "6.0.0",
          "private": true,
          "description": "Example project from an angular.io guide.",
          "scripts": {
            "ng": "ng",
            "build:aot": "ng build --aot --prod --build-optimizer",
            "serve:aot": "ng serve --aot --port 59384",
            "build": "ng build --prod --build-optimizer --vendor-chunk=true",
            "start": "ng serve --port 59384",
            "test": "ng test",
            "lint": "tslint ./src/**/*.ts -t verbose",
            "e2e": "ng e2e",
            "build:universal": "npm run build:client-and-server-bundles && npm run webpack:server",
            "serve:universal": "node dist/server.js",
            "build:client-and-server-bundles": "ng build --prod && ng build --prod --app 1 --output-hashing=false",
            "webpack:server": "webpack --config webpack.server.config.js --progress --colors"
          },
          "keywords": [],
          "author": "",
          "license": "MIT",
          "dependencies": {
            "@angular/animations": "^6.0.0",
            "@angular/common": "^6.0.0",
            "@angular/compiler": "^6.0.0",
            "@angular/core": "^6.0.0",
            "@angular/forms": "^6.0.0",
            "@angular/http": "^6.0.0",
            "@angular/platform-browser": "^6.0.0",
            "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^6.0.0",
            "@angular/router": "^6.0.0",
            "@angular/upgrade": "^6.0.0",
            "@nguniversal/express-engine": "^6.0.0",
            "@nguniversal/module-map-ngfactory-loader": "^6.0.0",
            "angular-in-memory-web-api": "^0.6.0",
            "core-js": "^2.5.4",
            "rxjs": "~6.1.0",
            "rxjs-compat": "^6.1.0",
            "rxjs-tslint": "^0.1.4",
            "zone.js": "^0.8.24"
          },
          "devDependencies": {
            "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.6.0",
            "@angular/cli": "^6.0.0",
            "@angular/compiler-cli": "^6.0.0",
            "@angular/platform-server": "^6.0.0",
            "@types/core-js": "^0.9.46",
            "@types/jasmine": "~2.8.0",
            "@types/jasminewd2": "^2.0.3",
            "@types/lodash": "^4.14.108",
            "@types/node": "^10.1.0",
            "angular2-recaptcha": "^0.6.0",
            "angulartics2": "^6.0.0",
            "braintree-web": "^3.33.0",
            "braintree-web-drop-in": "^1.10.0",
            "font-awesome": "^4.7.0",
            "hammerjs": "^2.0.8",
            "jasmine-core": "~2.99.1",
            "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
            "karma": "~1.7.1",
            "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.2.0",
            "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~1.4.2",
            "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.1",
            "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
            "karma-phantomjs-launcher": "^1.0.2",
            "lodash": "^4.17.10",
            "phantomjs-prebuilt": "^2.1.7",
            "protractor": "~5.3.0",
            "reflect-metadata": "^0.1.12",
            "requirejs": "^2.3.5",
            "source-map-explorer": "^1.5.0",
            "ts-node": "^5.0.1",
            "tslint": "^5.9.1",
            "typescript": "^2.7.2",
            "typings": "^2.1.1"
          },
          "repository": {}
        }
```

main.server.ts

```
        export { AppServerModule } from './app/app.server.module';
```

main.ts

```
        import { enableProdMode } from '@angular/core';
        import { platformBrowserDynamic } from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';

        import { AppModule } from './app/app.module';
        import { environment } from './environments/environment';

        if (environment.production) {
          enableProdMode();
        }

        platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule);
```

app.server.module.ts

```
        import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
        import { ServerModule } from '@angular/platform-server';
        import { ModuleMapLoaderModule } from '@nguniversal/module-map-ngfactory-loader';

        import { AppModule } from './app.module';
        import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

        @NgModule({
          imports: [
            AppModule,
            ServerModule,
            ModuleMapLoaderModule
          ],
          providers: [
            // Add universal-only providers here
          ],
          bootstrap: [ AppComponent ],
        })
        export class AppServerModule {}
```

server.ts

```
        // These are important and needed before anything else
        import 'zone.js/dist/zone-node';
        import 'reflect-metadata';

        import { enableProdMode } from '@angular/core';

        import * as express from 'express';
        import { join } from 'path';

        // Faster server renders w/ Prod mode (dev mode never needed)
        enableProdMode();

        // Express server
        const app = express();

        const PORT = process.env.PORT || 4000;
        const DIST_FOLDER = join(process.cwd(), 'dist');

        // * NOTE :: leave this as require() since this file is built Dynamically from webpack
        const { AppServerModuleNgFactory, LAZY_MODULE_MAP } = require('./dist/server/main.bundle');

        // Express Engine
        import { ngExpressEngine } from '@nguniversal/express-engine';
        // Import module map for lazy loading
        import { provideModuleMap } from '@nguniversal/module-map-ngfactory-loader';

        app.engine('html', ngExpressEngine({
          bootstrap: AppServerModuleNgFactory,
          providers: [
            provideModuleMap(LAZY_MODULE_MAP)
          ]
        }));

        app.set('view engine', 'html');
        app.set('views', join(DIST_FOLDER, 'browser'));

        // TODO: implement data requests securely
        app.get('/api/*', (req, res) => {
          res.status(404).send('data requests are not supported');
        });

        // Server static files from /browser
        app.get('*.*', express.static(join(DIST_FOLDER, 'browser')));

        // All regular routes use the Universal engine
        app.get('*', (req, res) => {
          res.render(join(DIST_FOLDER, 'browser', 'index.html'), { req });
        });

        // Start up the Node server
        app.listen(PORT, () => {
          console.log(`Node server listening on http://localhost:${PORT}`);
        });
```

webpack.server.config.js

```
        const path = require('path');
        const webpack = require('webpack');

        module.exports = {
          entry: { server: './server.ts' },
          resolve: { extensions: ['.js', '.ts'] },
          target: 'node',
          // this makes sure we include node_modules and other 3rd party libraries
          externals: [/(node_modules|main\..*\.js)/],
          output: {
            path: path.join(__dirname, 'dist'),
            filename: '[name].js'
          },
          module: {
            rules: [{ test: /\.ts$/, loader: 'ts-loader' }]
          },
          plugins: [
            // Temporary Fix for issue: https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/11580
            // for 'WARNING Critical dependency: the request of a dependency is an expression'
            new webpack.ContextReplacementPlugin(
              /(.+)?angular(\\|\/)core(.+)?/,
              path.join(__dirname, 'src'), // location of your src
              {} // a map of your routes
            ),
            new webpack.ContextReplacementPlugin(
              /(.+)?express(\\|\/)(.+)?/,
              path.join(__dirname, 'src'),
              {}
            )
          ]
        };
```

angular.json

```
            {
              "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular-devkit/core/src/workspace/workspace-schema.json",
              "version": 1,
              "newProjectRoot": "projects",
              "projects": {
                "angular.io-example": {
                  "root": "",
                  "projectType": "application",
                  "prefix": "app",
                  "architect": {
                    "build": {
                      "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
                      "options": {
                        "outputPath": "dist/angular.io-example",
                        "index": "src/index.html",
                        "main": "src/main.ts",
                        "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
                        "tsConfig": "src/tsconfig.app.json",
                        "assets": [
                          {
                            "glob": "favicon.ico",
                            "input": "src",
                            "output": "/"
                          },
                          {
                            "glob": "**/*",
                            "input": "src/assets",
                            "output": "/assets"
                          }
                        ],
                        "styles": [
                          {"input": "src/assets/css/styles.css"}
                        ],
                        "scripts": [
                          {"input": "node_modules/hammerjs/hammer.js"}
                        ]
                      },
                      "configurations": {
                        "production": {
                          "fileReplacements": [
                            {
                              "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                              "with": "src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
                            }
                          ],
                          "optimization": true,
                          "outputHashing": "all",
                          "sourceMap": false,
                          "extractCss": true,
                          "namedChunks": false,
                          "aot": true,
                          "extractLicenses": true,
                          "vendorChunk": true,
                          "buildOptimizer": true
                        }
                      }
                    },
                    "serve": {
                      "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",
                      "options": {
                        "browserTarget": "angular.io-example:build"
                      },
                      "configurations": {
                        "production": {
                          "browserTarget": "angular.io-example:build:production"
                        }
                      }
                    },
                    "extract-i18n": {
                      "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:extract-i18n",
                      "options": {
                        "browserTarget": "angular.io-example:build"
                      }
                    },
                    "test": {
                      "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:karma",
                      "options": {
                        "main": "src/test.ts",
                        "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
                        "tsConfig": "src/tsconfig.spec.json",
                        "karmaConfig": "src/karma.conf.js",
                        "styles": [
                          {
                            "input": "styles.css"
                          }
                        ],
                        "scripts": [],
                        "assets": [
                          {
                            "glob": "favicon.ico",
                            "input": "src/",
                            "output": "/"
                          },
                          {
                            "glob": "**/*",
                            "input": "src/assets",
                            "output": "/assets"
                          }
                        ]
                      }
                    },
                    "lint": {
                      "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:tslint",
                      "options": {
                        "tsConfig": [
                          "src/tsconfig.app.json",
                          "src/tsconfig.spec.json"
                        ],
                        "exclude": [
                          "**/node_modules/**"
                        ]
                      }
                    }
                  }
                },
                "angular.io-example-e2e": {
                  "root": "e2e/",
                  "projectType": "application",
                  "architect": {
                    "e2e": {
                      "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:protractor",
                      "options": {
                        "protractorConfig": "e2e/protractor.conf.js",
                        "devServerTarget": "angular.io-example:serve"
                      }
                    },
                    "lint": {
                      "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:tslint",
                      "options": {
                        "tsConfig": "e2e/tsconfig.e2e.json",
                        "exclude": [
                          "**/node_modules/**"
                        ]
                      }
                    }
                  }
                }
              }
            }
```

Comment: Was server side rendering working before , i mean the project in angular4 ?

Comment: Nop, it's our first attempt with angular 6, the application was running with that code, from A2 then A4 and A6 as AOT or JIT but not server-side

Comment: How you setup the server side rendering ? I meant show us the config file. This is issue of configuration.

Comment: I follow exactly the same structure as https://angular.io/guide/universal, however I'll add my ts config to the post

Comment: I test the code as well in typescriptlang.org and got the same error

Comment: Oops! You're missing CLI configuration otherwise Angular will know pick the `tsconfig.server.json` instead  `tsconfig.json` (Which is default). Check here https://angular.io/guide/universal#angular-cli-configuration

Comment: Btw, You mentioned , `0 /* testOne */..valueOf()` this is the error. Are you sure this is double dot (`..`)? The code in working in my laptop without error, however I checked the compiled code, it's single dot (And it should be)........ Anyway, try to setup the `tsconfig.server.json` in CLI config and let me know

Comment: I think the problem is "const" in the enum

Comment: yep! May be I just check that - different behavior.  Try to remove that. But `tsconfig.server.json` is also not configured in CLI config `angular.json`